# ssh: Connection refused when access remotely

Tags: ssh, fedora

I recently installed ssh server openssh-server in my fedora 16. I added my friend user account to my sshuser list. When my friend tried to connect my server computer via ssh using following command

ssh sudip@192.168.1.123

then it shows following error

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
```

but when i tried locally from my machine the server was connected.

```
root@localhost /]# ssh sudip@192.168.1.123
sudip@192.168.1.123's password: 
Last login: Tue Feb 26 13:24:42 2013 from localhost.localdomain
[sudip@localhost ~]$
```

Also, my firewall is allowing SSH and SHH is running on port 22.
So how can i troubleshoot the error??

thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
I already started sshd using **service sshd restart**

**EDIT2:**
output of: iptables -n -L -v

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
46970   23M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   11   616 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  133  8552 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
 2328  343K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 59145 packets, 7665K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Edit 3: result of `traceroute 192.168.1.123`

```
traceroute to 192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.50.1 (192.168.50.1)  0.828 ms  0.805 ms  0.818 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

The workstation also uses fedora 16

Comment: From where does your friend connect? Out of the same building/network?

Comment: he is on the same network. The ping command ping 192.168.1.123 works fine.

Comment: Can you show the output of `iptables -n -L -v` from server?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Can we also see the contents of `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`?

Comment: both files are empty

Comment: What do the logs on the ssh server say?

Comment: You can `iptables -Z INPUT` to drop the counters. Then try to `ssh sudip@192.168.1.123` from work station. Then take a look at `iptables -n -L -v`. There should be some digits (not zero) on the line "0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22"

Comment: @slimsuperhero there is not such digits. Instead there is zero

Comment: Show me please `traceroute 192.168.1.123` from your work station. BTW, what OS are you running on the work station?

Comment: @slimsuperhero: I have updated my question

Comment: There is at least one router (192.168.50.1) between the work station and server. So, besides your server's `iptables` rules, it could be other rules on routers which could drop your packets. You could try `tcpdump -i ethX port 22` on your server and try to ssh to it from work station to see if any packets goes in (don't forget to replace ethX with actual name of the world-looking iface). However, without complete understaning of your network topology, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Can you ping your ssh server from your friend's workstation? `ping 192.168.1.123`

Comment: @Huygens ping works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh -vvv user@192.x.x.x to get debug info on the connection. If -vvv is too much info you can use -vv or -v for less detailed debug info.

On the remote server, you should be able to see some info in /var/log/message or /var/log/syslog also.

A combo of those 2 things should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

The `Connection Refused` message generally means that nothing is listening on that ipaddress:port. Check to see that sshd is listening on your 192.168.1.123:22

```
netstat -tnlp | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      6809/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::22               :::*                LISTEN      6809/sshd
```

The above output is indicating that sshd is listening on all available ipv4 and ipv6 interfaces. If yours is different then you should check the `ListenAddress` directives in your sshd_config file.

Comment: Since it's possible to connect from another client, that's unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: @JennyD: The OP says  `locally from my machine` which suggests that the connection will have been via lo.

Comment: I checked it is listening on 192.168.1.123:22

Comment: Hmm this is interesting `netstat -tnlp` gives me an empty response. The sshd server is running according to `ps aux | grep sshd`. I tried with a socket server too, it was able to access localhost, but connection refused by using the local ip. The machine does not have firewall installed, so I have no clue what is wrong. Telnet gives me connection refused too.

Answer (score 1):

Executing ssh -vv sudip@192.168.1.123 will show you the detailed info of the SSH connetion. Also you can try "telnet 192.168.1.123 22" (telnet hostname port) in order to verify whether port 22 is listening.